# Setting params in HTTP POST request for swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsurlsession

I am making a post request with following params in HTTPBody:

filter:{“name”:"john”,”city”:”NY"}

I googled it but couldn't find the syntax

```
let params : [Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>] 
= [
            [
                "filter" : [
                    "name":"john",
                    "city":"NY"
                ]
            ]
        ]
  requestURL.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
```

Could you please help me setting the above params in Swift code?
Is there any syntax to put those params in HTTPBody?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct syntax :

```
var params: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> = [
    "filter" : [
        "name" : "john",
        "city" : "NY"          
    ]
]
```

Comment: It is not working! Do you know any other syntax to put this params in filter:{“name”:"john”,”city”:”NY"}